# Avoiding code duplication for methods with different return types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have two builder classes that return a `Tree` and a `Set` respectively. The execution of the second builder is just the execution of the first builder with an extra step and a different return type. I really don't want to duplicate the same steps in two different classes, because if there is a change in the `Tree`-building process, I have to change code in two classes. Here are the two builders:

```
public class TreeBuilder {

    private NodeHelper nodeHelper;

    public TreeBuilder(NodeHelper nodeHelper) {
        this.nodeHelper = nodeHelper;
    }

    public Tree<EquipmentDetails> buildTree() {

        Tree<EquipmentDetails> tree = new Tree<>(nodeHelper.getEquipmentDetails(nodeHelper.getModelName()));

        return buildTree(tree);
    }

    private Tree<EquipmentDetails> buildTree(Tree<EquipmentDetails> parentTree) {

        Map<String, NativeSlotDisplayLabel> childSubTypeMap = nodeHelper.getChildSubTypeMap(parentTree);

        if (CommonUtils.nullOrEmpty(childSubTypeMap))
            return parentTree;

        for (String holderCommonName : childSubTypeMap.keySet()) {

            NativeSlotDisplayLabel nativeSlotDisplayLabel = childSubTypeMap.get(holderCommonName);

            EquipmentDetails equipmentDetails = nodeHelper.constructEqptDetails(holderCommonName, nativeSlotDisplayLabel, parentTree);

            Tree<EquipmentDetails> childTree = new Tree<>(equipmentDetails);

            parentTree.addChild(childTree);

            String equipmentCommonName = equipmentDetails.getModelEquipType();

            if (equipmentCommonName == null)
                continue;

            buildTree(childTree);
        }

        return parentTree;
    }
}
```

The second builder uses one more dependency and returns a `Set` instead of a `Tree`:

```
public class FreePortsBuilder {

    private NodeHelper nodeHelper;

    private PortLabelGenerator portLabelGenerator;

    public FreePortsBuilder(NodeHelper nodeHelper, PortLabelGenerator portLabelGenerator) {
        this.nodeHelper = nodeHelper;
        this.portLabelGenerator = portLabelGenerator;
    }

    public Set<PortNameAndLabel> collectFreePorts(){

        Tree<EquipmentDetails> tree = new Tree<>(nodeHelper.getEquipmentDetails(nodeHelper.getModelName()));

        Set<PortNameAndLabel> portNameAndLabels = new HashSet<>();

        return collectFreePorts(tree, portNameAndLabels);
    }

    private Set<PortNameAndLabel> collectFreePorts(Tree<EquipmentDetails> parentTree, Set<PortNameAndLabel> portNameAndLabels) {

        Map<String, NativeSlotDisplayLabel> childSubTypeMap = nodeHelper.getChildSubTypeMap(parentTree);

        if (CommonUtils.nullOrEmpty(childSubTypeMap))
            return portNameAndLabels;

        Set<PortNameAndLabel> generatedPortNameAndLabel = portLabelGenerator.getPortNameAndLabel(childSubTypeMap, parentTree.getUserObject());

        portNameAndLabels.addAll(generatedPortNameAndLabel);

        for (String holderCommonName : childSubTypeMap.keySet()) {

            NativeSlotDisplayLabel nativeSlotDisplayLabel = childSubTypeMap.get(holderCommonName);

            EquipmentDetails equipmentDetails = nodeHelper.constructEqptDetails(holderCommonName, nativeSlotDisplayLabel, parentTree);

            Tree<EquipmentDetails> childTree = new Tree<>(equipmentDetails);

            parentTree.addChild(childTree);

            String equipmentCommonName = equipmentDetails.getModelEquipType();

            if (equipmentCommonName == null)
                continue;

            collectFreePorts(childTree, portNameAndLabels);
        }

        return portNameAndLabels;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to avoid the duplication. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FreePortsBuilder` is doing two things at the same time:

1. Building a `Tree`: as you know, this is identical to what `TreeBuilder` does.
2. Building a `Set<PortNameAndLabel>`, where each `PortNameAndLabel` appears to be associated with a node or child (which is itself a `Tree`) in the final `Tree`.

Instead of doing the above two things simultaneously, do them sequentially. That is, in `FreePortsBuilder`, *first* use `TreeBuilder` to build the `Tree`, *then* traverse this `Tree` to construct the `Set<PortNameAndLabel>`. One way to do that is the following (I assume that your `Tree` class has a method like `getChildren()` that returns a `List<Tree<EquipmentDetails>>`).

First, allow a client to obtain a `TreeBuilder`'s `NodeHelper` by adding a getter:

```
public class TreeBuilder {
  private NodeHelper nodeHelper;

  public NodeHelper getNodeHelper() {
    return this.nodeHelper;
  }

  ...
}
```

Then, inject a `TreeBuilder` instead of a `NodeHelper` into `FreePortsBuilder` (`FreePortsBuilder` can use the `NodeHelper` that is in the `TreeBuilder`, because of the getter that we just added):

```
public class FreePortsBuilder {
  private TreeBuilder treeBuilder;
  private PortLabelGenerator portLabelGenerator;

  public FreePortsBuilder(TreeBuilder treeBuilder, PortLabelGenerator portLabelGenerator) {
    this.treeBuilder = treeBuilder;
    this.portLabelGenerator = portLabelGenerator;
  }

  public Set<PortNameAndLabel> collectFreePorts() {
    Tree<EquipmentDetails> tree = treeBuilder.buildTree();
    return collectFreePorts(tree);
  }

  private Set<PortNameAndLabel> collectFreePorts(Tree<EquipmentDetails> tree) {
    Set<PortNameAndLabel> portNameAndLabels = new HashSet<>();

    for (Tree<EquipmentDetails> child : tree.getChildren()) {
      Map<String, NativeSlotDisplayLabel> childSubTypeMap =
          treeBuilder.getNodeHelper().getChildSubTypeMap(child);

      if (CommonUtils.nullOrEmpty(childSubTypeMap))
        continue;

      Set<PortNameAndLabel> generatedPortNameAndLabel =
          portLabelGenerator.getPortNameAndLabel(childSubTypeMap, child.getUserObject());

      portNameAndLabels.addAll(generatedPortNameAndLabel);
    }

    return portNameAndLabels;
  }
}
```

Now, `FreePortsBuilder` can truly make use of the `TreeBuilder` implementation, and the code duplication is removed.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Thought of a similar solution like a month ago. But didnt go with that. The way you explained provided why this approach makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Strategy design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) or [Template Method](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) here. You have an algorithm here where only certain steps change (collectFreePorts & buildTree).

If you cannot use inheritance, you can use a similar solution to this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187872/template-method-within-one-class-without-subclasses-or-inheritance